# Old Gmail account cannot be accessed

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

Years ago, I created a Gmail account. I no longer have the user or password information, and my primary email account has changed.

Can I recover this?

Comment: How? If you don't know the username, how is anyone supposed to know what account it is you're trying to recover?

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Accounts Help there is a troubleshoot that could help you:

[Problems signing in to your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

[password-assistance page](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/?hl=en&ard=AHwGkRkjxxomEi6hBJc7nYewHQC2GHcRC_GZQPMmRXh32auZaEjiO1351PbeTkbaUptWcg3FLOsCcEKTvOIkc3TN12HTsdwmSnwKmFXcaMuvmYtUa5i_HCePnB1PwEMNo96ZMeKuKW0TkEgIvY0i3Rrhqk_4Z8RF2A) can help you. There are 3 options:

> Having trouble signing in?
>
> - I don't know my password
> - I don't know my username
> - I'm having other problems signing in

Select the **second option**(I don't know my username) and follow the instructions.